# How to configure Kafka to repeat uncommitted offset messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Suppose I have these messages on my topic:

```
[A, A, B, A, B]
```

A is processed successfully by my application, but B throws an unexpected exception. I thought changing [`ackOnError` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094537/3026886) would not commit offset and thus the listener would **repeat processing the same message until Kafka listener process the message without exceptions**. I have set `enable.auto.commit` and `ackOnError` to false but the listener is still jumping to next message, doesn't matter if message is A or B.

How can I accomplish this desired behavior to keep my listener trying to process same message until it succeeds without exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to replay failures.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current).